# не могу установить 1c bitrix на локальный сервер

Tags: битрикс, openserver

не получается установить 1c bitrix на локальный сервер,после задания базы данных появляется такая пустая страница,я уже устанавливал туда битрикс,но потом удалил и хотел заново
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если это локальный сервер, в чём проблема создать новую базу и установить Битрикс в новую директорию? зачем возиться с той же самой?

Comment: так я и создал новую папку в которую загрузил

Comment: а это как понимать? _я уже устанавливал туда битрикс,но потом удалил и хотел заново_

Comment: я имел в виду что устанавливал на локальный сервер и потом удалил папку и создал новую

Comment: папка с тем же именем? если да, то надо с другим. и, главное, базу надо другую. чтоб вообще ничего общего с предыдущей установкой не было

Comment: папка с другим именем,и базу пытаюсь создать новую там же в установщике,я уже всё перебровал,всегда после базы данных эта страница выскакивает и всё

Comment: _базу пытаюсь создать новую там же в установщике_ базу надо не в установщике создавать, а сперва самому создать на локальном сервере через PhpMyAdmin и использовать при установке параметры этой базы

Comment: phpmyadmin вообще не могу зайти,не помню данные пользователя и пароль.вернее помню,пароль на локальном сервере я везде одинаковый ставил,но он не заходит